# gradlew bundleRelease failed due to com.android.tools.lint

Tags: android, react-native

I have a problem with releasing my app. When I use `gradlew bundleRelease` I get this error

```
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-fs:lintClassPath'.
> Could not find lint-gradle.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.1.4).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.4/lint-gradle-26.1.4.jar
> Could not find lint.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint:26.1.4).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint/26.1.4/lint-26.1.4.jar
> Could not find lint-checks.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:26.1.4).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-checks/26.1.4/lint-checks-26.1.4.jar
> Could not find lint-api.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:26.1.4).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-api/26.1.4/lint-api-26.1.4.jar
> Could not find lint-kotlin.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-kotlin:26.1.4).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-kotlin/26.1.4/lint-kotlin-26.1.4.jar
> Could not find intellij-core.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:26.1.4).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/intellij-core/26.1.4/intellij-core-26.1.4.jar
> Could not find uast.jar (com.android.tools.external.org-jetbrains:uast:26.1.4).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/org-jetbrains/uast/26.1.4/uast-26.1.4.jar
> Could not find kotlin-compiler.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:kotlin-compiler:26.1.4).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/kotlin-compiler/26.1.4/kotlin-compiler-26.1.4.jar
```

but in develop mode application compiled successfuly.
in `android/build.gradle` I use `google()` before `jcenter()` but it didnt work, I also try it on `react-native-fs/android/build.gradle`.
my dependencies classpath are:

```
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
```

Comment: are you behind a vpn or something blocking the downloads?\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be because there is no lint check in debug mode and so you don't have the dependencies for lint in your cache.
I checked the links in your error and they work fine for me. 
Maybe using a VPN would work for you if you are in a restricted country.